# I'm having trouble excluding certain extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfoWO = new DirectoryInfo( 
    Server.MapPath( "Clients/" + 
GetDistFolderName( (int)Session[ "Distid" ] ) + "/Work_Orders" ) );

ListViewWorkOrders.DataSource = dirInfoWO.GetFiles();
ListViewWorkOrders.DataBind();
```

This is listing files with the extension `.db` I need to exclude those as an option. I have looked at other answer which use LINQ. But I have no idea how to get those to work.

Does anyone have an easy to follow answer for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListViewWorkOrders.DataSource = 
    dirInfoWO.GetFiles().Where(fInfo=> !fInfo.Name.EndsWith(".db"));
```

or

```
ListViewWorkOrders.DataSource = 
    dirInfoWO.GetFiles().Where(fInfo=> !fInfo.Extension == ".db");
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'EndsWith' and no extension method 'EndsWith' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.FileInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: right, they are 2 GetFiles() Method in different assemblies, I took the wrong one. One returns a string[], the one you need a FileInfo[]. Check edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListViewWorkOrders.DataSource = 
    dirInfoWO.GetFiles().Where(p => Path.GetExtension(p.Name) != ".db");
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'EndsWith' and no extension method 'EndsWith' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.FileInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JamesWilson My example does not contain EndsWith

Comment: Sorry here is the correct error message. Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.GetExtension(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Alright thank you both very much!  I was having a bunch of trouble getting this to work.